# Getting an {"message":"Invalid update pipeline operator: \"_id\""} error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, updates

I am trying to update two rows in my players table based on the id.  I am trying to use the updateMany method where id can be found in an array of id's but I am getting the  `{"message":"Invalid update pipeline operator: \"_id\""}` error.  I checked the array to make sure it is valid id's.  Here is my code

```
const winningTeam = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  req.body.forEach((element) => {
    element.wins += 1;
    element.lastPlayed = Date.now();
    element.percentage = (element.wins / (element.wins + element.wins)) * 1000;
  });
  let usersId = [];
  usersId.push(req.body[0]._id);
  if (req.body.length === 2) {
    usersId.push(req.body[1]._id);
  } 
  const player = await Player.updateMany({ _id: { $in: usersId } }, req.body);
  if (player) {
    res.status(200).json(player);
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Invalid Data");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$set` property for the update parameter. I'm not sure about the structure of your `req.body` but it should be something like this:

```
Player.updateMany({ _id: { $in: usersId } }, {$set: req.body});
```

instead of this:

```
Player.updateMany({ _id: { $in: usersId } }, req.body);
```

Take a look at docs for [updateMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)